# Showing Recent Messages 65 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, decentralized-applications

I am using

> Xcode : 12.0.1,
> "react": "18.1.0",
> "react-native": "0.70.1"

on integrating @walletconnect/react-native-dapp according to the docs async storage is giving error while building project [image]